# Finding all tables and fields on "many" side of relations with a certain table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, information-schema

in Sql Server 2005, I have a master table, and several other tables which are related to
this master through several one to many relations.
How can I find all tables and fields which are in relation with the
primary key in the master table, on "many" side?

I know I can extract this by querying views from INFORMATION_SCHEMA,
but I don't know where exactly I can find this info.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with some help on sql server groups
I use the following query, which returns me schema name, table and field name on one and many side of the relations:

```
SELECT
    SchemaParent.name AS ParentSchemaName, 
    TableParent.name AS ParentTableName, 
    ColumnParent.name AS ParentColumnName, 
    SchemaChild.name AS ChildSchemaName, 
    TableChild.name AS ChildTableName, 
    ColumnChild.name AS ChildColumnName
FROM         
    sys.foreign_key_columns AS kc INNER JOIN
        sys.objects AS TableChild ON kc.parent_object_id = TableChild.object_id INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas AS SchemaChild ON TableChild.schema_id = SchemaChild.schema_id INNER JOIN
        sys.objects AS TableParent ON kc.referenced_object_id = TableParent.object_id INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas AS SchemaParent ON TableParent.schema_id = SchemaParent.schema_id INNER JOIN
        sys.columns AS ColumnParent ON kc.referenced_object_id = ColumnParent.object_id AND kc.referenced_column_id = ColumnParent.column_id INNER JOIN
        sys.columns AS ColumnChild ON kc.parent_object_id = ColumnChild.object_id AND kc.parent_column_id = ColumnChild.column_id
ORDER BY ParentTableName, ChildTableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE

Comment: Thanks for info, I'll check them out.